# Are there any examples of Wargs/Skinchangers inhabiting dragons?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I was wondering if there were any historical examples in ASOIAF about Wargs or skinchangers inhabiting dragons? I have searched [here](http://towerofthehand.com/) and [here](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Main_Page) and have not been able to find any evidence either way. Thanks

Comment: Why not ask your real question, what the likelihood of one of the Starks warging a dragon is. Not good, if you ask me, as Drogon will belong to Dany, Victarion will charm one with his horn, also being Drogo reborn according to Mirri Maaz Duurs prophecy, and Dany will bestow the remaining dragon to Jon, because according to the prophecy of the Undying, he will be her last husband, and most likely the third head of the dragon.

Comment: Of course, that comment only makes sense if you consider Jon a Targaryen primarily, as a son of Rhaegar + Lyanna, and not a Stark. =P

Comment: @ TLP, you are right I am very curious about the fate of the Starks and how that relates to the dragons. I am glad you brought if up, but my main interest really was in Jon and Dany. I was wondering if Dany could be warg. Also, it is already established that Jon is a warg, so what happens if he does end up with a dragon (like you suggest)? Especially a certain white dragon.... with red eyes... but I am only a young girl and know little of such matters.

Comment: Dany is likely not a warg, as she has never been described to have such experiences. She has some sort of bond with her dragons, but it seems different from warging. What happens if Jon gets a dragon? I expect he would toast a choice few people, and melt some Others.

Comment: Nice thinking of matching Viserion and Jon, although Viserion's eyes are "molten gold", not red. I think Jon will remain out of commission for a while. Remember Dany's prophecy that said `A blue flower grew from a chink in a wall of ice, and filled the air with sweetness.` That may be Jon's body stored in an ice cell in the Wall, and Dany is as of yet far away from even thinking about going to the Wall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there haven't been any (yet).

Unfortunately I can't provide proof of their absence because there, of course, isn't any!

Comment: I am trying to remember, was Daenerys was having dreams from Drogon's perspective in the most recent book?

Comment: I did go hunting for that because I vaguely remembered Daenerys having dragon-esque thoughts, but couldn't find it.

Comment: @ S. Albano and @ dlanond, I do remember something similar to that, I will go hunting today and see if I can find anything. Thank you!

Comment: No, Dany never had any warging dreams. All the dragons are only ever depicted from her someone else's perspective. Compared to the many wolves' perspective, where they clearly have first person observations.

Comment: @ S. Albano, dlanod, and TLP, I found something interesting. It is not exactly like the warging dreams that the Starks have, but it is very similar. She seems to be turning INTO the dragon, flying herself, smelling smoke and salt... but you could also interpret it as a dragon flying over her and picking her up. It is just after she has her child and is in the midst of fever dreams. She dreams she is running faster and faster, then sprouts wings on her back and flies herself. The dream is analyzed here: http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/Prophecies/Entry/1798/

Answer (score -1):

Wargs are only bound to wolves, so it's impossible that one warg control a dragon.

Skinchanger is a more generic term, but I don't think it's possible, the books say it is very diffucult to control birds without driving yourself crazy, and a dragon is a much more powerful creature, with a stronger personality. I don't think it's possible.

In A Dance With Dragons, Daenerys can "communicate" with Drogon, but in a different way, not skinchanging (both keep the control of theirselves).

Comment: [Warg is used synonymously with skinchanger](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Warg), so your first sentence is incorrect. There's no restriction listed on what animals a warg can possess; in fact, it is explicitly stated that many other animals besides wolves are possible hosts (including humans!).

Comment: The old skinchanger Mance left to guard his wife and Jon was referred to as a warg even though he controlled a hawk and a shadowcat. There are other examples too but this one was the first to jump to mind.

Comment: That's not what George R.R. Martin says: "A warg is bound to a wolf. Skinchanger is a more general term. All wargs are skinchangers, but not all skinchangers are wargs."
http://boiledleather.com/post/28908673771/all-wargs-are-skinchangers-but-not-all-skinchangers

Comment: @greuze Hrm. I don't believe he sticks to that consistently, as I'm pretty sure he refers to some individuals not bound to a wolf as wargs in the books. Also, the phrasing doesn't mean that he's saying wargs are *exclusively* bound to wolves; Varamyr Sixskins, for example, was a warg who was bound to wolves, a shadowcat, a snow bear, and an eagle. Perhaps Martin was referring to the difference in bonding wolves (per the wiki): "Wolves, are harder, one has to forge a lasting bond, much like a marriage. A man might befriend a wolf, even break a wolf, but no man could truly tame a wolf."

Comment: Although now that I think about it, wasn't Varamyr identified as a warg *before* he bonded to his first wolf, back when he was bonding with the family dogs?